# R reactable - expand/ungroup single item groups created by groupBy()

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I'm trying to produce an interactive table using reactable in Shiny that only creates expandable groups for rows that contain multiple values under the single key variable.

```
library(reactable)
library(data.table)

data <- setDT(MASS::Cars93[10:22, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price", "MPG.city")])

reactable(data, groupBy = "Manufacturer")
```

[image: Example 1]
The table above shows only one entry under Chrylser - I would like this to be automatically expanded or ideally not have the expand arrow at all and show all information on the one line.

Some kludgy code produces a table which shows roughly what I want:

```
data_unique <- unique(data, by = "Manufacturer")
data_dups <- unique(data[duplicated(data, by = "Manufacturer")]$Manufacturer)
reactable(data_unique,
          columns = list(Manufacturer = colDef(details = function(index){
                                               if(data_unique[index]$Manufacturer %in% data_dups){
                                                  reactable(data[Manufacturer == data_unique[index]$Manufacturer,
                                                                                             c("Model", "Type")])
                                                  }})))
```

[image: Example 2]
Chrylser now no longer has an expand button and shows all its information in the one row. The main issue is the expand button produces a separate table that doesn't line up with the main table. I like the behaviour produced by the first example using groupBy(), so ideally I would have a combination of the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want to use it in `shiny`, I could think of using `JavaScript` to automatically trigger the click event:

```r
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), reactable(data, groupBy = "Manufacturer"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   session$onFlushed(function() {
      runjs('$(".rt-td>div>span").filter(function(idx, el) {return $(el).text().includes("(1)")}).trigger("click")')
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use 'aggregate' function to achieve this -

example:

```
 reactable(data,
                 groupBy = c("Manufacturer"),
                 resizable = TRUE,
                 ......
                 columns = list("Model" = colDef(aggregate = "unique"),
                                "Type" = colDef(aggregate = "unique")))
```